# Does the Javascript standard guarantee a deterministic result for ~0?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a duplicate question; was unable to find an answer anywhere.

Does the Javascript standard guarantee a deterministic result for `~0`?

Chrome gives me `-1` for `<script>alert(~0);</script>`.

Is this result guaranteed cross-browser (and cross-platform in general)?

Comment: Can you not test it? Like write a script which does this 1000 times, run it on all major browsers?

Comment: @CallumLinington I see what you're saying but this would only test the implementation not the specification.

Comment: @CallumLinington: Just added "cross-platform" as well... In any case, my question is specifically about the JS standard, so an empiric test, no matter how thorough, will not answer it.

Answer (score 2):

[The specification says](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-bitwise-not-operator),

> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Let oldValue be ToInt32(GetValue(expr)).
> 3. Return the result of applying bitwise complement to oldValue. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

The first step actually evaluates the expression. Second step converts the expression to a 32 bit integer. All implementations should implement this properly. The third step is simply to flip the bits in the number. There is only one way to do this.

So I would expect all the implementations to give the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's deterministic. From the MDN documentation of [bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT)

> Bitwise NOTing any number `x` yields `-(x + 1)`.

This is because the bitwise operators are based on [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation.